# How do I tell a Phoenix LiveView to update?

Tags: phoenix-framework, phoenix-live-view

I understand that I can get the liveview to update by including something like:

```
if connected?(socket), do: :timer.send_interval(10000, self(), :click)
```

But, is there a way to trigger this from somewhere else in my application?

For example, if you are updating traffic stats, you only want to update the control when a new click has arrived.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the PubSub mechanism. E.g. set `Phoenix.PubSub.subscribe` on `mount` and `broadcast` in a click `handle_event`